# Returning Distinct Count of a Column in a Query

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I'm rather new to SQL, but I have a question regarding counting rows in a query I've built already.

Basically, I have the query down to what I need, but there are duplicate entries in the main column I'm trying to isolate. Is there any way to simply add a DISTINCT COUNT statement and bracket in the query to return the count on a specific column?

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[X] INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[Y]
     ON [dbo].[X].[B] = [dbo].[Y].[B]
WHERE [A] = 'F'
```

I basically want to count distinct values on the [dbo].[X].[B] column only,

Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, use `COUNT(DISTINCT COL)`...

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just include the keyword DISTINCT inside the count parentheses().

```
COUNT(DISTINCT [X].[B])
```

Comment: Thanks, first time I've ever asked a question here, so I formatted it poorly, where exactly do I put this in context of the query itself?

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [dbo].[X].[B]) FROM 

(SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[X] INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[Y]
     ON [dbo].[X].[B] = [dbo].[Y].[B]
WHERE [A] = 'F')?

Comment: Just replace * in the query you posted above with that count. There is not need to select from this result set again.